# What is the use of sessions table in drupal?

Tags: drupal

What is the use of sessions table in drupal?
Sometimes this table is crashed, Can anyone please tell me the reason it is crashed?

Comment: Ankur, just a tiny tip: it often helps to tag with your version of Drupal when asking Drupal questions.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sessions table keeps track of user sessions on your site. This table should have an entry for every user that's logged in to your site.  Some users may even have more than one session entry if they're logged in from different devices or even different browsers.

You can select the table and 'repair' it from your phpMyAdmin interface, or as a last resort manually empty it, but that will log out all users from your site.  I hope this helps...

It's hard to know why it's crashing, but if it's happening very frequently, it sounds like a module you have installed may be causing problems.  I'm assuming you haven't modified any code in Drupal core.

Comment: my addition: this should have an entry for every session. if you logged in to your site from 2 devices without logging out or login expiring, 2 entries in session table.

Comment: You're exactly right, Ayesh!  Thanks for adding that.  I have three sessions in the session table as admin even now, because I often log in from three different browsers to test.  ;-)  I've modified my answer so it's a little clearer!

Comment: Thankyou Boriana and Ayesha for the answer. It is really helpful for me

Comment: It has an entry for every user accessing your site; even anonymous users. Not just logged in as suggested in the "answer".